# код запускается не с начала

Tags: python, ооп, функции, скрипт

Имеется скрипт на пайтон. В нем импортируется другая библиотека (строка 6) и подразумевается ее вызов в нужном месте. Где необходимо происходит вызов библиотеки. Но код запускается не с моего начала, а с вызванного в конце скрипта. Какой скрипт вызывается не важно.(в смысле того что какой бы не вызывал начинает с него)

```
import os
import time
score = 0
ForChek = 0

import snake_test



print('Добро пожаловать! Напишите Ваше имя пожалуйста.')
***
print('Начинаем квест! Ну точнее не начинаем... Ну точнее не квест... В общем, выбирай 
первую задачку!')
while ForChek == 0:
    GameStart = input('Выбирай! Змейка или пинг-понг(с искусственным интеллектом) ')
    if GameStart == 'змейка':
        ForChek += 1;
    elif GameStart == 'пинг-понг':
        ForChek += 1;
    elif GameStart != 'змейка' and GameStart != 'пинг-понг':
    print("ЧТо-то пошло не по плану... Можете еще раз?")
        time.sleep(1)


if GameStart == "змейка":
    snake_test.gameLoop()
```

Comment: можно увидеть содержимое `snake_test`?

Comment: @Denis yadi.sk/d/dsLveuR-7liqlw вот

Comment: в snake_test уберите самую последнюю строку, т все заработает нормально

Comment: @Danis 1) но я этой функцией вызываю саму змейку
2) ну допустим, но не заработало...
https://yadi.sk/i/jmXZPfBES-Aq5w

Comment: @Danis заработало, но в начале появляется окно пайгейма,а когда доходит до момента где нужен вызов как раз таки и в том окне все как надо. Как сделать чтобы и окно(на скрине выше) появлялось на моменте вызова функции,а не в начале?

Comment: можно snake_test импортировать в предпоследней строчке, после `if`a но до `snake_test.gameloop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в `snake_test` уберите самую последнюю строку, и все заработает нормально

чтобы окно `pygame`'а открывалось в концеможно `snake_test` импортировать в предпоследней строчке, после `if`'а но до `snake_test.gameloop`

Answer (score 1):

Очень подозреваю, что в скрипте snake_test имеется явно прописанный вызов некоторой  функции (например,для тестирования)  или вообще какие-то операторы, не обернутые в вызов функции, а вот конструкция `if __name__ == "__main__":` не используется

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/dsLveuR-7liqlw вот код cnake_test

Comment: @VladimirPodolich вся информация связанная с вопросом должна быть в самом вопросе, а не где-то на внешних обменниках.